# Windows 2008 list open files and close certain file

Tags: windows, dfs

My main goal is to find specific file in specific shared folders amongst a DFS and to close them at midnight.

My problem is that "net file" command does not list full path, example : e:...\folder\file.doc

I need full path to determine wether a file is to be closed or not.

We were using handle.exe from SysInternals before, but it is not working on Win2008 x64..

Anyone got an idea?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my question :

To obtain full path you have to type the following command :

> openfiles /query /fo LIST

It seems that you have to know /query to use it... see :

> openfiles /query /?

Hope this help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

To close a specific file, use

```
openfiles /disconnect /a * /op "D:\Directory\file.txt"
```